# Pause execution in vim

Tags: vimrc

Is it possible to do something like this in vim:

```
function MyFunction
    echom "Part 1"
    raw_input('...') # python equivalent (or input(...) in python3)
    echom "Part "2"
endfunction
```

That is, a way to pause execution either for the user to enter input or to just pause the function until the user hits enter?

Comment: You could just do `:h input<C-d>` this will list all help topics containing the word `input`. This will lead you to `:h input()`.

Comment: @Ralf thank you that was the help I needed to point me in the right direction and I was able to apply it.

Comment: @Ralf I never knew about `<C-d>` -- actually I mapped it on my keyboard so that it acts like a normal unix delete-forward-char -- but perhaps I should undo that mapping so I can use it for autocomplete on help.

Comment: David, you can write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your other questions, it looks like you are familiar with Python.
You can refer to the following gist which compares the various Python
programming constructs with the corresponding VimScript constructs:

https://gist.github.com/yegappan/16d964a37ead0979b05e655aa036cad0

Comment: wow that's awesome. Did you write that? It's so thorough and super useful to me, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se] Yegappan, so great to have you here!